# How to get the desired labels on ticks on the x-axis in a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
x = array([0], [1], [2], [3] ...[175])

y = array([333], [336], [327], ...[351])
```

Both have the shape (175,1)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(5.5, 5.5)
plt.plot(x, y, color='blue')
```

I get this result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbQ9n.jpg

But I wanted separate labels on my x-axis ticks, taken from this array

```
year = array([1974], [1974], [1974], ....[1987])
```

which also has the shape (175,1) but a lot of repeating values

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(5.5, 5.5)
plt.plot(year, y, color='blue')
```

Gives https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8IPb.jpg

And

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(5.5, 5.5)
plt.plot(x, y, color='blue')
ax.set_xticklabels(year)
```

Gives https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvrw8.jpg

I want the resultant plot as obtained in first figure but the labels on xticks as obtained in the second figure

Comment: Probably you mean to use `ax.set_xticks(np.unique(year.flatten()))`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I think using that I got the right labels this time but they all now appear squished together at the bottom right corner of the plot https://i.imgur.com/WLsgLOZ.jpg

Comment: Oh, in that case I do not understand how `year` relates to `x`. If `x` are no years, how would you know which year is which x.

Comment: But ```ax.set_xticklabels(np.unique(year.flatten()))``` seems to have worked. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that. Maybe it kind of works by coincidence if you don't care about leap years.

Comment: You are right. It didn't work. The years 1984-1987 are missing. https://i.imgur.com/n6VwlK8.jpg

Comment: Can you convert `x` to decimal years somehow, ie. `xnew = x / 12. + 1974` or whatever unit x is in?

Comment: @Jody x is just the index of a dataframe that has two attributes: Carbon emissions data (that I have denoted by y) and the year in which it was recorded. The data has monthly frequency. So the year column has a lot of repeating values. One can also easily plot "y" without specifying "x" in plt.plot. "x" doesn't really matter, now that I realize. The problem is correctly labeling the year on the x axis. Plotiing "y" with "year" gives the second plot that I have shared in the question, which is certainly not accurate.

Answer (score 1):

If I combine the suggestions in the comments of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest and @Jody Klymak you could:

- change the x values into a meaningful value, instead of only an index (counter value), i.e. time expressed in years (float values).
- then you could use `set_xticks` to specify what the tick labels you want to see

for instance:

```
# mimic your data a little bit
x = np.arange(0, 175)
y = 330.0 + 5.0 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x / 13.0) + x / 10.0

# change the x values in something meaningful
x_in_years = 1974.5 + x / 13.0

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(5.5, 5.5)
plt.plot(x_in_years, y, color='blue')

# select the ticks you want to display    
ax.set_xticks([1975, 1980, 1985, 1990])
# or
# ax.set_xticks([1974, 1978, 1982, 1986])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to inputs from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, @Jody Klymak, and @Jan Kuiken.

So, instead of setting the labels on x-axis ticks, it's better to set the desired ticks.

Since "year" is not compatible with "y" for the correct plot, I created another array that is obtained from "year" and is also compatible to plot with "y".

```
start = year.min().astype(float)
end = year.max().astype(float)

step = (year.max() - year.min())/len(year)
x = np.arange(start, end, step)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(5.5, 5.5)
plt.plot(x, y, color='blue')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987])
plt.grid(color='y', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)
```

Plot obtained - https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtlEh.jpg

Comment: This looks much better, however you have to be careful to be exact. Did the `y` samples start at beginning of 1974 or later during that year? Same question for the ending of the samples in 1987. Are all samples taken after exactly the same time duration? Do you have additional information about the sample time (month, date)?

Comment: Yes, good point. The data is not uniform. It starts in August of 1974 and ends in May of 1987. Also some 10 or 12 instances are missing. So, this is still not perfect.